# minimal polynamial of $i\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2} \in C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Find the minimal polynamial of $i\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2}\in C$ over rational numbers.

My solution is;

Say $\alpha=i\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2}$

$(\alpha-\sqrt{2})^2=(i\sqrt{5})^2$

$\alpha^2-2\sqrt{2}\alpha=-5$

$\alpha^2 +7=2\sqrt{2}\alpha$

$\alpha^4 +6\alpha^2+49=0 $

how I say one is minimal ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\alpha^2-7=2\sqrt5\alpha i$?

Comment: And in the last one, shouldn't the $14\alpha$ term be $14\alpha^2$?

Comment: for last one, you're right

Comment: Fixed my first comment

Comment: I editted question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could argue that the degree of $\mathbb{ Q }( \sqrt{2} + i \sqrt{5})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is four.

Or just argue that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It is obvious that degree of Q(2√+i5√) over Q is four (for me) If I say degree is four, than I mean this polynomail is irredicuble?

Comment: Yes.  If $K$ is a field and $u\in K$ is algebraic with minimum polynomial $f \in K[x]$, then $[K(u) : K] = \deg f$.  Also, if $g\in K[x]$ is any polynomial with $g(u) = 0$, then  $f$ divides $g$.  The polynomial you constructed is monic and degree 4 and the min poly divides your polynomial, so they must be equal.